# Route that returns a file

Tags: angular

I have a REST API where some resources are files like images or PDF files. These files I want to display in my Angular2 application.
Until now, it wasn't a problem, I would just use the URL from the api directly in the `<img src` attribute for example.
However, that has now stopped working as I secured the API via Bearer Token Authentication.

What is the correct way to solve this?
I thought about creating a route in my Angular2 application that internally calls the Web API URL with the proper authentication and returns the result to the caller.
But I have no idea how to actually implement that...

Answer (score 0):

In your component class you create a method that makes the request for you and sets the correct auth headers for the request. You then bind the response value of the method call to your img src attribute.

Of course, the image will not display until the call has resolved (but that would have applied previously).